# Outer Apply with case statement and Xpath inside returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My table has 3 columns:

- EmployeeId
- Active
- Data

Data is XML type that holds subjects and marks. I need to extract mark and subject from XML, but when the employee id InActive, I need to just return a single result as NULL even though the XML has Subject and Mark.

Below is the query I tried and I got following error.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
SELECT eo.employeeid, 
       Result.marks.[Subject], 
       Result.marks.[Mark] 
FROM   employee eo 
       OUTER apply (SELECT CASE 
             WHEN eo.active = 0 THEN (SELECT NULL AS 'Subject', 
                                             NULL AS 'Mark') 
             ELSE ((SELECT f.n.value('@Subject', 'varchar(100)') 
                           AS 
                           'Subject', 
                           f.n.value('@Mark', 'int') 
                           AS 
                           'Mark' 
                    FROM   eo.data.nodes('(/Employee/Results)') AS 
                           F(n))) 
           END AS marks) Result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @employee TABLE
(
employeeid INT IDENTITY(1,1),
active BIT,
data XML
);

INSERT INTO @employee(active, data)
VALUES
(1, N'<Employee><Results Subject="subject 1" Mark="111"/></Employee>'),
(1, N'<Employee><Results Subject="subject 2" Mark="222"/></Employee>'),
(0, N'<Employee><Results Subject="subject 3" Mark="333"/></Employee>');

SELECT 
    eo.employeeid, eo.active,
    f.n.value('@Subject', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Subject', 
    f.n.value('@Mark', 'int') AS 'Mark' 
FROM
(
    SELECT employeeid, active,
        CASE active WHEN 1 THEN data END AS data
FROM @employee
) AS eo
OUTER APPLY eo.data.nodes('Employee/Results') AS F(n);
```